# Question about component name (DrMOS?)

Tags: identification, driver, mosfet-driver, gpu

I'm trying to find the fault on my GTX 970 card and it seems that I have found at least one of the problems. There seems to be a DrMOS(?) that after plugging the power in is getting hot to the touch and anything else stays cool to the touch.

The problem is that I cannot find this exact DrMOS's datasheet from anywhere to clear things up. It is driving me crazy that there are sets of numbers/letters on it, but there are no corresponding results when using Google.

I would be really thankful if anyone could tell me the code/name under what I would be able to find a bit more information about the component.

[image: Photo 1 of unknown device on PCB]

[image: Photo 2 of unknown device on PCB]

[image: Photo 3 of unknown device on PCB]

Original high-resolution images:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1AJP99G8KE7MugQwyeYlKBmCahREtboaV